# C# error With ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

Recently I was trying to build an app that can read excel files. But just after I select the excel file I get an error saying this:

> 'ExcelDataReader.Exceptions.HeaderException' occurred in
> ExcelDataReader.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid file signature."
>
> The error is caught on line 38

here is a copy of my code

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Alt_jde
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    DataSet result;
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() )
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(ofd.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);   // ERROR HERE
                var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = true
                    }
                });
                cbosheet.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                    cbosheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                reader.Close();
                    }
        }
    }

    private void cbosheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView.DataSource = result.Tables[cbosheet.SelectedIndex];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you positive the file your working with in an xls/xlsx/csv file?

Comment: yes i am @AlexK. it is an xlsx file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The code calls `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader` which is for the XLS format.

Instead, change to use `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader` for the XLSX format specifically, or use `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader` to autodetect either XLS or XLSX formats transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not in the correct format.
Open your file in Microsoft Office and "Save as" again in '.xls' format and use this new file.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with what the OP is asking